# What's the price of adding a checked in luggage after buying a flight ticket with Scoot but before going to the airport?

Tags: air-travel, luggage, price, scoot

I wonder what the price is of adding a checked in luggage after buying a flight ticket with Scoot but before going to the airport.
I [read](https://wise.com/au/blog/scoot-luggage-allowance#:%7E:text=Note%20that%20additional%20baggage%20can,for%20Scoot%20airline%20services%20here.):

> If you want to carry more luggage that your ticket will cover, you can buy additional allowance when you buy your ticket, after purchase, or at the airport. Note that additional baggage can be purchased up to 4 hours before your scheduled departure online by clicking on “Manage my booking” or by phoning the call centre.
>
> You’ll find all fees for Scoot airline services [here](https://www.flyscoot.com/en/plan/booking-your-flight/fares-fees).
>
> The exact costs will depend on when you’re buying the additional allowance, and how heavy your extra bags are. To get the specific costs for your flight you’ll need to head to the Scoot website and use the fee calculator there.

But I go to that [page](https://www.flyscoot.com/en/plan/booking-your-flight/fares-fees) that is supposed to contain "all fees for Scoot airline services", it only mentions the fees of adding luggage at the airport, and not fees of adding luggage up to 4 hours before the scheduled departure online by clicking on “Manage my booking” ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4AzpD.png)). I'd prefer not trying to contact the customer of a low-cost airline. Can that fee be found somewhere else? Or is the fee simply the same at adding the luggage at the airport?

Comment: I think the airport fee is _in addition_ to the cost of the extra luggage if you buy it at the airport. The cost of additional weight is available on the site (after selecting the origin/destination pair), but I'm not sure about the cost of adding luggage to a ticket which does not include any.

Comment: @jcaron Thanks, I think it's the entire fee of adding the luggage at the airport, but airlines never cease to impress me, so maybe you're right. In the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4AzpD.png) of the page, I don't see the price of adding the luggage when purchased online after buying the flight ticket.

Comment: Possibly the price depend on the flight (so on the demand). Just try to buy a baggage, without confirming it, so you should get the price. Of just try a fake booking (without giving payment information and without confirming the purchase).

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi Thanks, this would give me the price of buying the luggage at the time of booking, but not the price of buying the luggage after booking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my experience (N=1), **the add-on price is the same as buying when you originally book**, you only have to pay extra if you show up at the airport without prebooking.

Anecdotal evidence: in April this year, I bought a Scoot ticket with one piece of baggage for $60.  In September, I realized one would not be enough and added another, which also cost $60.

I presume the wording is the way it is because Scoot can change baggage fees (for all flights) at any time, so the new fee could have been more, or theoretically even less.

Answer (score 3):

In my experience (N=1), adding a 20kg checked-in luggage 10 hours after buying the flight ticket is ~30% more expensive that buying that luggage at the same time as buying the flight ticket.

On [Reddit](https://redd.it/186fh33) ([mirror](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eYfgE.jpg)), two people say that the price of adding a checked-in luggage after buying the flight ticket is cheaper than at the airport but more expensive that buying that luggage at the same time as buying the flight ticket. The same two people say that claim that the price changes daily.